Prove $\frac{\sin (\frac{7 \theta}{2} )}{\sin (\frac{\theta}{2} )}=2 \cos (3 \theta )+2\cos (2 \theta )+2 \cos (\theta )+1 $
Prove the following trigonometric identity:
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\sin\left (\frac{7 \theta}{2}\right )}{\sin\left (\frac{\theta}{2}\right )}=2 \cos\left (3 \theta\right )+2\cos\left (2 \theta\right )+2 \cos\left (\theta\right )+1.
\end{equation*}
I have attempted a solution. However, I am looking for alternative or possibly more elegant approaches.
My attempt:
Define $A$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
  A =2 \cos\left (3 \theta\right )+2\cos\left (2 \theta\right )+2 \cos\left (\theta\right )+1
\end{equation*}
Using Euler's formula, we can rewrite $A$ in terms of complex exponentials:
\begin{equation*}
  A =e^{i 3\theta}+e^{-i 3 \theta}+e^{i 2 \theta}+e^{-i 2 \theta}+e^{i \theta}+e^{-i \theta}+1 \end{equation*}
This can be expressed as a sum of a geometric series:
\begin{equation*}
  A  =\sum_{n=-3}^{n=3} e^{\left (-i \theta\right )^n}
\end{equation*}
Applying the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we have:
\begin{align*}
  A &=\frac{e^{-i \theta \left (-3\right )} - e^{-i \theta \left (3+1\right )}}{1-e^{-i \theta}} \\
   & =\frac{e^{-i \frac{\theta}{2}}}{e^{-i \frac{\theta}{2}}} \cdot \frac{e^{i \frac{7 \theta}{2}} - e^{- i \frac{7 \theta}{2}}}{e^{i \frac{\theta}{2}} - e^{- i \frac{\theta}{2}}} \\
   & = \frac{2i \cdot \sin\left (\frac{7 \theta}{2}\right )}{2i \cdot \sin\left (\frac{\theta}{2}\right )} \\
   & = \frac{\sin\left (\frac{7 \theta}{2}\right )}{\sin\left (\frac{\theta}{2}\right )}
\end{align*}

please write \sin and \cos instead of sin and cos

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos{k\theta}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac12\left[\sin{\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}-\sin{\left(\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}\right]\
&=\frac12\left[\sin{\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}-\sin{\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}\right]\
&=\frac12\left[\sin{\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}-\sin{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right].
\end{align} Take $n=3$ and $\sin\frac\theta2\neq0$.

Setting $$q=e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$$you have $$\frac{q^7-q^{-7}}{q-q^{-1}}=q^6+q^4+q^2+1+q^{-2}+q^{-4}+q^{-6}$$

Related: "How can we sum up sin and cos series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"

Here is a shorter way:
$\dfrac{\sin\left(\!\frac{7\theta}2\!\right)}{\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}=$
$\!\!\!\!=\!\!\dfrac{\color{blue}{\sin\!\left(\!\frac{7\theta}2\!\right)\!\!\!-\!\!\sin\!\left(\!\frac{5\theta}2\!\right)}\!\!\!+\!\!\color{red}{\sin\!\left(\!\frac{5\theta}2\!\right)\!\!\!-\!\!\sin\!\left(\!\frac{3\theta}2\!\right)}\!\!\!+\!\!\color{green}{\sin\!\left(\!\frac{3\theta}2\!\right)\!\!\!-\!\!\sin\!\left(\!\frac{\theta}2\!\right)}\!\!\!+\!\!\sin\left(\!\frac{\theta}2\!\right)\!\!\!\!}{\sin\!\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}\!\!=$
$\!\!\!\!=\!\!\dfrac{\color{blue}{2\!\cos\left(3\theta\right)\!\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}\!\!+\!\color{red}{2\!\cos\left(2\theta\right)\!\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}\!\!+\!\color{green}{2\!\cos\left(\theta\right)\!\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)} \!\!+\!\sin\left(\!\frac{\theta}2\!\right)\!\!\!}{\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}\!\!=$
$=\dfrac{\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)\bigg[2\cos(3\theta)\!+\!2\cos(2\theta)\!+\!2\cos(\theta)\!+\!1\bigg]}{\sin\left(\!\frac\theta2\!\right)}=$
$=2\cos(3\theta)\!+\!2\cos(2\theta)\!+\!2\cos(\theta)\!+\!1\;.$

It's definitely not more elegant than yours (or Riemann's) but here's an alternative.
$$\frac{\sin(\frac{7\theta}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{7\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})}=\frac{\sin4\theta+\sin3\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
$$=\frac{(2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta)+(\sin2\theta\cos\theta+\sin\theta
\cos2\theta)}{\sin\theta}$$
$$=\frac{2(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\cos2\theta+(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\cos\theta+\sin\theta
\cos2\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
$$=2(2\cos\theta\cos2\theta)+2\cos^2\theta+
\cos2\theta$$
$$=2(\cos3\theta+\cos\theta)+(1+\cos2\theta)+\cos2\theta$$
$$=2\cos3\theta+2\cos2\theta+2\cos\theta+1$$

Adding 1 on both sides, we get
$\frac{\sin\left (\frac{7 \theta}{2}\right )+sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\sin\left (\frac{\theta}{2}\right )}=2 \cos\left (3 \theta\right )+2\cos\left (2 \theta\right )+2 \cos\left (\theta\right )+2$.
$\frac{2sin(4\theta)cos(\frac{3\theta}{2})}{sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}=2[cos(3\theta)+cos(2\theta)+cos(\theta)+cos(0)]$
Using sum of  cosine of angles in A.P formula, we get the RHS to be
$$\frac{2sin(4\theta)cos(\frac{3\theta}{2})}{sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$$
Which is equal to L.H.S. Hence proved.

Multiply the right side by $\sin(\theta/2)$ and apply the sum-product relation
$2\cos(u)\sin(v)=\sin(u+v)-\sin(u-v).$
Thereby
$2\cos(3\theta)\sin(\theta/2)=\sin(7\theta/2)-\sin(5\theta/2)$
and similarly for the terms with $\cos(2\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$. You cancel out a lot of terms and obtain the claimed result.

Your way is fine and it is a special case of the more general Lagrange's trigonometric identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \cos k\theta  = \frac{\sin \tfrac12\theta + \sin\left(\left(n + \tfrac12\right)\theta\right)}{2\sin\tfrac12\theta}$$
from which we obtain
$$2 \cos\left (3 \theta\right )+2\cos\left (2 \theta\right )+2 \cos\left (\theta\right )+1 =2\left(\sum_{k=0}^3 \cos k\theta\right)-1 =2\frac{\sin \frac \theta 2 + \sin \frac {7\theta} 2}{2\sin\frac \theta 2}-1 = \frac{\sin\frac{7 \theta}{2}}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}$$
